# converting python POST request into R httr POST request

Tags: r, python-requests, rest, httr

I have the following code in python which returns a 200 status:

```
>         credentials = {
>         'grant_type': 'client_credentials',
>         'scope':'various scopes go here'
>     }

> response = requests.post('https://sample_website.com/oauth/token', 
>                         headers = {"Authorization": "Basic {}".format(signed_request), 
>                                    "Content-Type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"},
>                         data = credentials
>                         )
```

when i try the following code using the same signed_request I get a 401 error

```
credentials <- "{'grant_type': 'client_credentials','scope':'various scopes'}" 
response <- POST(url = 'https://sample_website.com/oauth/token', 
                 add_headers(
                              Authorization = signed_request,
                             'Content-Type' = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
                             ),
                 accept('application/json'),
                 body = credentials, 
                 encode = 'json',
                 verbose()
                 )
```

I can't figure out what I am doing wrong but I'm assuming that I am not formatting the body correct or there might be an issue with the headers I am passing.

Answer (score 1):

Your body is appropriate for the content type "application/json", but not for "x-www-form-urlencoded". The easiest solution is to pass a list, and let R take care of serialising it for you.

```r
body <- list(
    grant_type="client_credentials",
    scope="scopes"
)
POST(url=*,
    add_headers(Authorization=paste("Basic", signed_request)),
    body=body,
    encode="form"
)
```

Depending on what it is you're doing, you may also want to try the [httr2](https://cloud.r-project.org/package=httr2) package (the successor to httr) and its built-in OAuth authentications options, among which is [client credentials](https://httr2.r-lib.org/reference/req_oauth_client_credentials.html).

Comment: Thanks for the response! When I try this I get the following error: "Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) : HTTP/2 stream 0 was not closed cleanly: PROTOCOL_ERROR (err 1).      I can't find any useful info on this error

Comment: Try it again xyz